# Not able to get lightning input type checkbox values in JS controller

Tags: lightning-aura-components

We are replacing ui names space tags with lightning name space tag in the lightning component since they are going to deprecating soon.

We are displaying multiple languages with checkbox’s . When users selects check box language value should update in backend. While using ui:inputCheckbox tag we are able to update the  language but if we use  lightning:input type="checkbox" language values updating as Boolean value (True) in the back end instead of check box values. Below is the peace of code.

```
<aura:attribute name="selectAllLanguages" type="Boolean" default="false" />
  <aura:attribute name="languages" type="Object[]" />
 <aura:iteration items="{!v.languages}" var="lang">
  <lightning:input type="checkbox"  value="{!lang.isSelected}" aura:id="boxPackLanguages" />
   <!--<ui:inputCheckbox text="{!lang.language}" value="{!lang.isSelected}" aura:id="boxPackLanguages" />--> 

</aura:iteration>
```

JS Code:

```
var languagesSelected = false;
var getAllLanguages = component.find("boxPackLanguages"); 
   if(getAllLanguages != null){
            //if there's only one language
            if (getAllLanguages[0] == null) {
                languagesSelected = true;
                languages.push(getAllLanguages.get("v.value"));
            }
            
            for (var i = 0; i < getAllLanguages.length; i++) {
                if (getAllLanguages[i].get("v.value") == true) {
                    languagesSelected = true;
                    languages.push(getAllLanguages[i].get("v.value"));
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Lightning Checkboxes use the attribute `checked`, which is consistent with the HTML specification, rather than the ui:inputCheckbox, which called it value. You'll need to set the `checked` attribute to set the value, and read this value to determine if the box is checked.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using lightning:checkboxGroup instead.
You can see the documentation at https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:checkboxGroup/example along with controller example to get values.